# First option in the context menu is highlighted without hovering the mouse from javafx 9

Tags: javafx, java-9

when we right click for context menu, the first option in the list is being highlighted without hovering the mouse. This happens only for the first time right click after the application is opened. This behavior is observed from javafx-9. Till javafx-8 its working fine.

Tried with the sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleContextMenu extends Application {
    // labels
    Label l;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // launch the application
        launch(args);
    }

    // launch the application
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // set title for the stage
        stage.setTitle("creating contextMenu ");

        // create a label
        Label label1 = new Label("This is a ContextMenu example ");

        // create a menu
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        // create menuitems
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("menu item 1");
        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("menu item 2");
        MenuItem menuItem3 = new MenuItem("menu item 3");

        // add menu items to menu
        contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem1);
        contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem2);
        contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem3);

        // create a tilepane
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane(label1);

        // setContextMenu to label
        label1.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

        // create a scene
        Scene sc = new Scene(tilePane, 200, 200);

        // set the scene
        stage.setScene(sc);

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like a bug to me, at least in win the expected behavior seems to be to highlight menuItems only if the mouse hovers over them. There's also another quirk in that the highlight is not removed when the mouse is moved completely off the contextMenu

Comment: I have created a bug here [JDK-8227679](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8227679)

Comment: thanks for filing :) commented the report with a link to this question and answer ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of digging, turns out that the culprit (so to say) is the default focus traversal on initially showing of a scene - which is to focus the first focusable node, which in the case of a contextMenu is the first item.

**First try** of a hack-around: request the focus back onto the scene's root when the item is focused. The steps:

- register a onShown handler on the contextMenu
- in the handler, grab the scene that contains the contextMenu: at this time, its focusOwner is still null, so we need to register a changeListener on its focusOwner property
- in the listener, on first change of the focusOwner (the old value is null), request focus on the root and cleanup the listeners

Beware: this is not good enough, turned out to be a cosmetic hack only, there are several glitches as noted in the comments

- requesting the focus to the scene root disables keyboard navigation
- the first item is still active: pressing enter activates its action

**Next try** (now going really dirty, requiring access to hidden implementation details of non-public classes!): replace the last step of the first try by

- grab the containing ContextMenuContent (internal class in com.sun.xx), it's the grandparent of the focused item
- request focus on that content to make the highlight disappear
- update that content to be aware of no-item-focused (reflective access to private field)

In code:

```
contextMenu.setOnShown(e -> {
    Scene scene = contextMenu.getScene();
    scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener((src, ov, nv) -> {
        // focusOwner set after first showing
        if (ov == null) {
            // transfer focus to root
            // old hack (see the beware section) on why it doesn't work
            //  scene.getRoot().requestFocus();

            // next try: 
            // grab the containing ContextMenuContainer and force the internal
            // book-keeping into no-item-focused state
            Parent parent = nv.getParent().getParent();
            parent.requestFocus();
            // reflective setting of private field, this is my utility method, use your own ;)
            invokeSetFieldValue(ContextMenuContent.class, parent, "currentFocusedIndex", -1);
            // cleanup
            contextMenu.setOnShown(null);

         }
    });
});
```

For convenience, here's the utility method for reflective access of internal fields (no rocket sciene, just plain java ;)

```
public static void invokeSetFieldValue(Class<?> declaringClass, Object target, String name, Object value) {
    try {
        Field field = declaringClass.getDeclaredField(name);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(target, value);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code is working fine when we use mouse. But unable to navigate through options in the context menu if we use keyboard keys as the focus is outside of the context menu.

Comment: I have checked with fx11, until we highlight any option on the context menu focus is outside the context menu.

Comment: yeah, you are right: requesting the focus not on the root but on the parent of the focused item does keep the keyboard navigation, with a glitch: on down, the second item gets focused (because the internals of ContextMenuContainer still have the first marked as active) And another glitch with this fake-focus: open and press enter will fire the action of the first item .. darn. Needs more work, sry.

Comment: The modified solution is better than the first one, but with keyboard navigation second option is highlighted directly skipping the first option.

Comment: worksforme  - pressing down key after opening (by right-click) selects/highlights first item

Comment: I checked once again, pressing down key after opening by right-click selects second item. From the second time, its working fine.

Comment: then your experience is different from mine